Intuition cosets of $S_n$ under product of "subgroups"
Given group $S_n$ and subgroups $H, G$ that are identified as $S_2$ and $S_{n-2}$ (i.e. the subgroups that permute the first two and the last $n-2$ elements and are as such isomorphic to $S_2$ and $S_{n-2}$; by abuse of notation write $S_2$ and $S_{n-2}$ ), is there an "intuitive" way to think of the cosets of $S_n / (S_2 \times S_{n-2})$ (direct product).
(Especially I read that this can be identified with elements $\alpha_{ij}, i \lt j$, with $S_n$ acting $\delta \alpha_{ij} =  \alpha_{\delta(i) \delta (j)})$
I did calculate the cosets in small cases i.e. $S_3$ and $S_4$ and wasn't able to extrapolate anything out of that, I guess im searching something in the line of "since cosets identify elements in $S_n$ that differ by the quotient, this means ... in this case"

$S_2$ is not a normal subgroup of $S_n$ for any $n$ other than $S_2$ itself, so what is $(S_n/S_2)\times S_{n-2}$ meant to be? It's not a group. What you apparently want is the subgroup of elements that map ${1,2}$ to itself and ${3,\ldots,n}$ to itself.

@ArturoMagidin yes that's correct (that's what identified was supposed to mean but edited for clarity)

Again: $(S_n/S_2)\times S_{n-2}$  is not a group, it is not a subgroup of $S_n$, and it does not have cosets in $S_n$. Put the correct, not nonsensical, statement of what you mean  in the post. The information needs to be in the post, not in the comments. Comments can disappear without a trace at any moment. Fix the post.

Let $G=S_n$, acting naturally on $X:=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $H=S_2\times S_{n-2}$ be the subgroup of $G$ that preserves $\{1,2\}$ setwise. Let $\binom{X}{2}$ be the set of unordered pairs of elements of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, so $\left|\binom{X}{2}\right|=\binom{n}{2}$. Note that $G$ has an obvious induced action on $\binom{X}{2}$. Now let $\alpha:G/H\to \binom{X}{2}$ be given by $\alpha(Hg)=\{1,2\}^g$. One can check that $\alpha$ is a bijection.
More generally, if $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup and you want to find a "natural" interpretation for $G/H$, then you can find some transitive action of $G$ such that $H$ is a stabiliser in this action and then defining $\alpha$ as above will give you a nice bijection between the coset space and the set $G$ is acting on.

Thank you for the answer (especially the more general approach)!

Some general context first. The denominator is called a Young subgroup, and in this case it's a maximal parabolic subgroup. The quotients are basic building blocks in the representation theory of the symmetric group. They generate the Grothendieck group, though with subtraction; this is basically the $h$ basis of symmetric functions.
More concretely, let $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k)$ consist of positive integers summing to $n$. Let $S_\alpha = S_{\alpha_1} \times \cdots \times S_{\alpha_k}$, where the $i$th factor permutes $\alpha_i$ letters in the middle as usual. Let $W_\alpha$ consist of all words with $\alpha_i$ copies of the letter $i$ for each $i$. Essentially by definition, $|W_\alpha| = \binom{n}{\alpha}$ is a multinomial coefficient.
Note that $S_n$ acts on $W_\alpha$ naturally by permuting the letters. Consider the word $w$ with $\alpha_1$ copies of $1$ followed immediately by $\alpha_2$ copies of $2$, etc. Note that the stabilizer of $w$ in $S_n$ is precisely $S_\alpha$. Obviously $S_n$ acts transitively on $W_n$. Consequently, the map $\sigma S_\alpha \mapsto \sigma w$ is a bijection from $S_n/S_\alpha$ to $W_\alpha$, and indeed it is $S_n$-equivariant.
When $\alpha=(2, n-2)$, the words in question are completely determined by the subset of size two consisting of where the 1's are.
We get isomorphic representations if we simply rearrange the parts of $\alpha$, so we often put them in decreasing order and use integer partitions $\lambda$ of $n$. After doing so, we get pairwise non-isomorphic representations. I won't go into too many details, but one way to see this is that permutations of cycle type $\mu$ have fixed points in $W_\lambda$ only if $\mu \leq \lambda$ in dominance order. This is a partial order giving upper triangularity of the (square) character matrix in question with non-zero diagonal entries, so the representations are distinct even over $\mathbb{C} S_n$. By standard character theory, since the character matrix is invertible, they generate the Grothendieck group. It's not obvious, but the irreducible representations over $\mathbb{C} S_n$ also live in the $W_\lambda$'s as something like a "top component".
